# How do I make the first Card in a ListView.builder already clicked when widget is displayed

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have a ListView.builder that shows Tasks Fetched from Firebase and allows the users to select one of them, now I don't want the widget to be in a state where not one task is clicked (this widget is only displayed if there are actual tasks to display), How do I make it so the first card is already clicked when the widget is rendered?

The first class:

```
class TaskListWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const TaskListWidget({super.key});
  //updating timeslot in the cards onTap

  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final taskList = ref.watch(taskListProvider);

    // String? selectedTask;

    return Container(
      height: 56,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.76,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), // Adjust the radius as needed
      ),
      child: taskList.when(
        loading: () => const CircularProgressIndicator(),
        error: (error, stackTrace) => Text('Error'),
        data: (data) {
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              String taskPick = data[index];
              //Initialisng it to already have clicked the first one
              //  ref.read(selectedTaskProvider.notifier).changeString(taskPick);
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  ref
                      .read(selectedTaskProvider.notifier)
                      .changeString(taskPick);
                },
                child: Card(
                  color: ref.watch(selectedTaskProvider) == taskPick
                      ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onTertiaryContainer
                      : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                  //  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
                  elevation: 4,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 113, // Adjust this width as needed

                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          data[index],
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the selectedTask Provider:

```
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'selected_task.g.dart';

@riverpod
class SelectedTask extends _$SelectedTask {
  @override
  String build() {
    return '';
  }

  void changeString(String newString) {
    state = newString;
  }
  // Add methods to mutate the state
}
```

and the taskListProvider:

```
@riverpod
class TaskList extends _$TaskList {
  @override
  Future<List<String>> build() async {
    final dbhandler = DBHandler();
    return await dbhandler.getUserTasks();
  }
}
```

And on a Second Note in my Theme class I have a light and dark mode and when a button in the appBar is clicked the entire app switches to dark mode and this is where I have a problem because the card Only changes color, When one of the cards are clicked and doesn't when the entire app switches to dark mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'd suggest You to use a ConsumerStatefulWidget, and in the initState() method use ref.read(...) to load the state (the **read**() works as the **watch**() method but it does not "**dirt**" the widget, thus it will not be repainted, in this case it is not an error, it is ok because you are in the init phase).

Then set something like:

```
int  _selectedCardIndex = 0;
```

and manage it as a 'plain' stateful widget state.
update it with setState(...) and use it instead of using a riverpod state.

So, use riverpod only to handle data, but to change graphics, selections, animations, use an internal state of a "plain" StatefulWidget, it should be easer.